# Are AspMvc RouteCollections reset every request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

As the question says, with asp mvc is the RouteCollection object reset for each request... I thought it was set on an application level not per request.

== Edit ==

To give more context to why I am asking this question.

I currently have a web app which has 2 default routes and uses MEF to load additional routes in dynamically from plugins, now I was wondering why my routes were not appearing in the route table debugger, and when debugging every request was calling the plugins with the current routetable, but it had only the default routes.

So every request it *appeared* to be sending the plugins a new route table with only the 2 default routes, it then adds lets say 5 more routes bringing the total to 7, however then on next refresh it is back down to 2.

So I was a bit puzzled as to why it keeps seemingly resetting the routes constantly.

Comment: The routing table isn't reset.  What makes you think it is?  I think you need to be more clear about what you're doing.  If it *was* reset, nothing would ever work after the first request.

Comment: Yes it would, it would just re-register the routes each request, thats what I was wondering about, as I didnt think it was. Will update the main question with my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route registration is generally done in `Application_Start` which runs only once. They *could* be cleared with something like `RouteTable.Routes.Clear()`, but it doesn't sound usual for them to be reset.

That said, I don't know anything about MEF, so it's possible that registering routes through it behave differently to how you'd usually do it in Global.asax in a template-created MVC site.

Comment: I am not calling RouteTable.Routes.Clear() anywhere, so I am baffled as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: The routedebugger *may* be doing some clearing somewhere along the line, but without having that in I cannot tell which routes are being exposed.